# Rendering lists in JSP

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I'm having a problem trying to output an array in a JSP:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/searchResult.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
ModelAndView search(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws SQLException
{
    String keyword = request.getParameter("keyword");

    String within = request.getParameter("witin");

    String status = request.getParameter("status");

    String query="select id,title,description,story_type,uploaded_date,popularity from story where status='"+status+"' and title like '"+'%'+keyword+'%'+"'";
     stmt= (Statement) DBManager.getMyConnection();
     rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
     Map map = new HashMap();
     List wordList = new ArrayList();
     if(keyword!=null){
          while (rs.next()) {
          String id = rs.getString("id");
          String title = rs.getString("title");
          String description = rs.getString("description");
          String parent = rs.getString("uploaded_date");
          String type = rs.getString("story_type");
          String pop = rs.getString("popularity");
          wordList.add(id);
          wordList.add(title);
          wordList.add(type);
          wordList.add(description);
          wordList.add(parent);
          wordList.add(pop);
          map.put("wordList", wordList);
           }
          return new ModelAndView("searchResult",map);
     }
      return new ModelAndView("search");
}
```

in the JSP I use `${wordList}` which  prints

> [20, india won worldcup, sports, this
>   is my cup, 2011-03-26, 2, 27, india
>   won worldcup, sports, xyz, 2011-04-08,
>   2]

...these are two records in one array.

How can I print each item in a separate row in a JSP?

Answer (score 2):

Your variable called wordList is a collection. To display elements of a collection you can use forEach.

There is a good example of this available [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jstl0318/) and a shorter example [here](http://www.kodejava.org/examples/526.html).